# Database doesn't do INSERT for array data set

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

My whole code is given below. I have an array `$members` storing some IDs. I run a loop to search for those IDs in a table, retrieve their respective names and store them in another array `$members_name`. I then insert both the arrays in my table. The size of `$members` array is between 1-6.

```
<?php
    session_start();
        $members = $_POST['mem'];
        $n=count($members);
        foreach($members as $key=>$value){
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,email FROM users WHERE id='".$value."'");
            if ($res === false) {
                echo mysql_error();
                die;
            }
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

            if($row['id'])
            {
                $members_name[]=$row['name'];
                $members_email[]=$row['email'];
            }
        }
        $sess_uid = $_SESSION['id'];
        $sess_email = $_SESSION['email'];
        $sess_name = $_SESSION['name'];
        $id=$_SESSION['eid'];
        $name=$_SESSION['ename'];
        $members=$_SESSION['emembers'];

        if ($n==5){
            $res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO eventregistration(event_id,event_name,event_members,mem_1_id,mem_1_name,mem_2_id,mem_2_name,mem_3_id,mem_3_name,mem_4_id,mem_4_name,mem_5_id,mem_5_name,mem_6_id,mem_6_name) 
      VALUES('".$id."','".$name."','".$members."','".$sess_uid."','".$sess_name."','".$members[0].",'".$members_name[0]."','".$members[1].",'".$members_name[1]."','".$members[2].",'".$members_name[2]."','".$members[3].",'".$members_name[3]."','".$members[4].",'".$members_name[4]."')");
        }
        else if ($n==4){
            $res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO eventregistration(event_id,event_name,event_members,mem_1_id,mem_1_name,mem_2_id,mem_2_name,mem_3_id,mem_3_name,mem_4_id,mem_4_name,mem_5_id,mem_5_name) 
      VALUES('".$id."','".$name."','".$members."','".$sess_uid."','".$sess_name."','".$members[0].",'".$members_name[0]."','".$members[1].",'".$members_name[1]."','".$members[2].",'".$members_name[2]."','".$members[3].",'".$members_name[3]."')");
        }
        else if ($n==3){
            $res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO eventregistration(event_id,event_name,event_members,mem_1_id,mem_1_name,mem_2_id,mem_2_name,mem_3_id,mem_3_name,mem_4_id,mem_4_name) 
      VALUES('".$id."','".$name."','".$members."','".$sess_uid."','".$sess_name."','".$members[0].",'".$members_name[0]."','".$members[1].",'".$members_name[1]."','".$members[2].",'".$members_name[2]."')");
        }
        else if ($n==2){
            $res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO eventregistration(event_id,event_name,event_members,mem_1_id,mem_1_name,mem_2_id,mem_2_name,mem_3_id,mem_3_name) 
      VALUES('".$id."','".$name."','".$members."','".$sess_uid."','".$sess_name."','".$members[0].",'".$members_name[0]."','".$members[1].",'".$members_name[1]."')");
        }
        else if ($n==1){
            $res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO eventregistration(event_id,event_name,event_members,mem_1_id,mem_1_name,mem_2_id,mem_2_name) 
      VALUES('".$id."','".$name."','".$members."','".$sess_uid."','".$sess_name."','".$members[0].",'".$members_name[0]."')");
        }
        else if ($n==0){
            $res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO eventregistration(event_id,event_name,event_members,mem_1_id,mem_1_name) 
      VALUES('".$id."','".$name."','".$members."','".$sess_uid."','".$sess_name."')");
        }
        $url="events.php?slug=".$slug;
            header('Location: ' . $url);
            exit;
?>
```

I'm still a learner in PHP. I know I'm using the OLD format of PHP. Still I need help in running this page and not about PDO.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to stop using `mysql_` functions as they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.
2. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.
3. Your table structure is not normalized. There is absolutely no reason you need to have a column for `n` members.
4. Instead of performing logic for every `n` members, throw them into an array and create a dynamic column list.

Comment: I know they are deprecated, but I wanted to get the page working first.